where can i find guide to intergare my large language model to OneApi,thank you
I'm new to large language models. My manager wants me to integrate our large language model to OneApi, silimar to Llama 3 in OneApi, but I can't find the documentation or sample code for the interface.
Thank you very much for your reply.
i used google ,but failed to find something.
